# Python Selenium Select Dropdown

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new in selenium and html and I have below Dropdown list to be selected.

[image]

```
<div id="type" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="width: 152px;">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden">
        <select id="type_input" name="type_input">
            <option value="-1">Select...</option>
            <option value="1425934311">Apple</option>
            <option value="1332693877">Manggo</option>
            <option value="-661889110">Guava</option>
            <option value="-2142431953">Melon</option>
            <option value="-1217708884">Banana</option>
            <option value="1848482159">Pineapple</option>
            <option value="-1978925920">Dragon</option>
            <option value="-2071056077">Blueberry</option>
            <option value="1663124412">Raspberry</option>
            <option value="1577647363">Cerry</option>
            <option value="-1900558530">Grape</option>
            <option value="662655762">Watermelon</option>
            <option value="492725061">Strawberry</option>
            <option value="1585488306">Lemon</option>
            <option value="-194293497">Avocado</option>
            <option value="-999909285">Dates</option>
            <option value="-271862289">Pomegranate</option>
            <option value="-668526874">Kiwi</option>
            <option value="1553315664">Papaya</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <input id="type_focus" name="type_focus" type="text">
    </div>
    <label id="type_label" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all" style="width: 111.667px;">Select...</label>
    <div class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

However all method that i have tried always not working either using select or webdriverwait. Any help would be appreciate what cause my script not working.

Method 1

```
select_sor = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='type_input']"));
select_sor.select_by_index(2)
```

Method 2

```
select_sor = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='type_input']")))
select_sor.click()  
select_sor_2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='type_input']/option[2]")))
select_sor_2.click()  
type here
```

Method 3

```
# wait for dropdown to exist
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "type_input")))

# expand housing type dropdown using javascript
dropdown_trigger = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='type_input']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", dropdown_trigger)

# select an option -- this selects 'flat'
dropdown_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='type_input']/option[2]")))
dropdown_option.click()type here
```

Comment: 1. Can you share the URL of the application if it is public? 2. You have not mentioned what error/exception you get for each method you have tried, can you edit the question and share error trace? 3. Check for the presence of `IFRAME`.